# RequireNonce is 'true' (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null in Azure Traffic Manager , OpenIdConnectAuthentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rm-template, azure-traffic-manager

I have my website(Azure App Service) deployed in two regions under Microsoft Azure . 
https://abcd1-westus.azurewebsites.net/ 
https://abcd2-centralus.azurewebsites.net/ 
I created a Traffic Manager Profile to control the distribution of user traffic for service endpoints. The DNS Name of Traffic Manager Profile is "http://abcd.trafficmanager.net"
Authentication is done by Azure AD . 
Once we are trying to access Traffic Manager DNS Url , it prompts for AAD login and redirect to https://abcd2.azurewebsites.net and the yellow page error comes up 
**"IDX10311: RequireNonce is 'true' (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null. A nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'."**
If I open individual website url it works perfectly. I have used the below code in StartUp.Auth.cs. I am using **Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect** , Version 3.1.0.0

```
public partial class Startup
{
    string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppKey"];
    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];
    string resource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Resource"];
    string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n => {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = n.OwinContext.Request.Uri.ToString();
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                }
            });
    }

    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        var code = context.Code;
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, resource);
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Production is close :(

Comment: I'm thinking the problem might be this. Your browser accesses the page first with the Traffic Manager URL. The nonce cookie is set on that domain. The user gets redirected back to a different URL. The cookie does not exist. So the middleware cannot validate it.

Comment: You should probably redirect to the Traffic Manager URL from AAD. Let me know if this works, and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @Junnas... I also guess the same as your first reply... Could not understand what you are trying to say in your second message. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Sure. My main point is that the URL the user sees in the address bar should be the same all the time. If they access the site over `https://abc.trafficmanager.net`, then Azure AD needs to redirect them to `https://abc.trafficmanager.net` after authentication. It must not use the azurewebsites.net URL at any time.

Comment: Yes... Now I understand... Thank you for comment. It got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can't mix the traffic manager URL and the Web App URLs.

The nonce cookie is set on the TM domain and the redirect back comes on a different domain. So the nonce cookie is not found.

So the URL the user sees in the address bar should be the same all the time. If they access the site over `https://abc.trafficmanager.net`, then Azure AD needs to redirect them to `https://abc.trafficmanager.net` after authentication. It must not use the azurewebsites.net URL at any time.

Comment: After reading up on how Traffic Manager works at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-how-it-works , it seems that the client should be making the request to the redirected endpoint (azurewebsites). Which in turn should trigger the authentication flow and the nonce cookie should be set for the azurewebsites domain.

I am also seeing the same behavior that you mentioned above. But cannot reason it with the TM documentation. May be I am missing some crucial information.